# Rewrite Magento core files

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, core

I have a **Magento 1.9.3.1** website in front of me right now in which the core files have been edited

( THEY HAVE COMMITTED A SIN!!! ).

Anyway I have figured out which files they have edited and I am currently working on removing all those custom lines of code.

However I need to keep the functions which have been added in the website but I don't know what I should do exactly or where to place them.

Is it as simple as placing the files in local or community? 
**( local = specific for this website. community = from the web and not specifically for this website ).**  And does this count for all the files? So right now I've found all the files they edited, these are the files :

> 1. app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/price.php
> 2. app/code/core/Mage/core/model/Email/Template.php
> 3. app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Controllers/AccountController.php
> 4. app/code/core/Mage/Customer/model/Customer.php
> 5. app/code/core/Mage/Customer/model/Session.php
> 6. app/Mage.php

Sadly I do not know if I should simply copy paste the code and add the lines of code in the custom liberary. I did google it though but I keep ending up at theme template posts...

Could you tell me where I should put the new files? and maybe if possible explain it too,
And in case I am doing this completely wrong, please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, it's forbidden to change or update the `core files`, so what you have to do is to rewrite all these core files.

`app/code/...` will be rewrited in **local codePool**.

`app/design/...` will be overrited in **current theme**.

Now according to this rules, your files will be rewrited of course in `local`.

You have good [This Inchoo explanation](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/) for rewriting blocks, helpers, controllers, etc...